# How to lock Postgresql table across multiple psycopg2 queries with python logic in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to update a postgresql table where the business logic for the updates is written in python and the database connection uses psycopg2. To ensure consistency, this will require locking the table. Loosely what I would like to do is:

1. Lock the table for updates (SHARE LOCK)
2. Query the table for some information
3. Given the state of that table and the user's input, determine how the table needs to change (python business logic)
4. Update the table
5. Unlock the table

The logic for determining the differences between the existing table's state and the user input will be done in python using pandas.

As I understand it, locks are per transaction, so in order to hold a lock on the table, all of this must happen as part of one SQL transaction. However, I need to lock for updates before querying the data and I have to run some business logic in python before actually updating the table. This sounds like two transactions to me, so I'm not sure how I can ensure that the data doesn't change during these steps. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Database transactions should never be that long – they should definitely never contain user interaction.

You have two options: add a table column `locked_at` or so and persist the "locks" that way (essentially, lock in the application) or use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) that can span several transactions.